# Read InputStream from file via URL query string

Tags: java, url, networking, junit, httpconnection

Is it possible to use the java URL.openStream() method to read the file into an input stream when the URL is a query string rather than a direct link to a file? E.g. the code I have is:

```
URL myURL = new URL("http://www.test.com/myFile.doc");
InputStream is = myURL.openStream();
```

This works fine for a direct file link. But what if the URL was http://www.test.com?file=myFile.doc ? Would I still be able to obtain the file stream from the server response?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: Because I'm unable to try it right now and I'd like to know how it works. I know that when there is a direct link I already have the location of the file, but when it is a query string, it is up to the server to return the location of the as content. I was curious how this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally YES, it will work.

But note that `URL.openStream()` method doesn't follow redirects and not so agile with specifying some additional HTTP behaviours: request type, headers, etc.

I'd recommend to use [Apache HTTP Client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/quickstart.html) instead:

```
final CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();         
final HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://any-url");

try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request)) {
    final int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    if (status == 200) {
        final InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
    } else {
        throw new IOException("Got " + status + " from server!");
    }
}
finally {
    request.reset();
}
```

Comment: many thanks for a useful response! With this particular resource, I am getting a 302 sent back from the query with the location. Would url.openStream() automatically resolve to the location? Or would I have to do something like you have there?

Comment: unfortunately, as I mentioned using `url.openStream()` you'll need to handle 3xx statuses and follow these redirects manually in some cyclic manner.
`HttpClients.createDefault()` follows redirects by default and do many useful things, look at official docs they are pretty user-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

The URL class works for any url, including:

- `new URL("http://www.example.com/");`
- `new URL("file://C/windows/system32/cmd.exe");`
- `new URL("ftp://user:password@example.com/filename;type=i");`

Its up to the application to do something with the data, for example download the data, or treat it as plain text.